# Commit doesn't show up in profile on Drupal site

Tags: community-official-site, version-control

I submitted a small patch on [no trigger dependencies in job_scheduler_trigger.info](http://drupal.org/node/1781212). It looks like the patch worked, but when I look at the commits tab of the drupal.org profile, I don't see any entry.

When using Git, I created a new branch for the issue, made the changes, and then checked in. Should I have switched back to the development branch and checked in?

Comment: The maintainer of the module has not committed the patch, yet. It is too early for the commit to appear in your user profile, if it is going to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commits submitted in the issue queue are only counted when the maintainer accepts them and credits you with the patch.  Otherwise, people could just spam useless patches through drupal.org to increase their commit counts.